# Adding an "or" to regex

Tags: regex

I have these strings:

```
[?q]this is a test[?p]
```

And

```
[?q]this is a test<RANDOM_TAG>
```

I want to get all the text between `[?q]` and `[?p]` **OR** `[?q]` and `<` 
Is it possible to do that in just one pattern?

I've done this so far:

```
[\\?q](.*?)(<)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following pattern:

```
\[\?q\](.*?)(?:\[\?p\]|<)
```

Working example [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kA9iN1).

---

**How it works:**

- `\[\?q\]` checks for the literal sequence `[?q]`
- `(.*?)` is the capturing group that gets any char sequence until it reaches either:

  - `\[\?p\]` (the literal sequence `[?p]`) or
  - `<`

To make the pattern look for **either** `[?p]` **or** `<`, I used a **non-capturing group**, `(?:...)` containing the two patterns I can match, separated by a `|`, which means **or**.

---

By the way, it seems that your pattern, `[\\?q](.*?)(<)?`, doesn't **escape** the **square brackets**... you need to do so, using `\` ;)

Also, it seems that you're escaping the `\` as well: are you using something like a **Java String** to create your pattern? If so, the actual Java `String` you need to use is the following:

```
"\\[\\?q\\](.*?)(?:\\[\\?p\\]|<)"
```

---

Example usage in Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (final String s : new String[] { "[?q]this is a test[?p]", "[?q]this is a test<RANDOM_TAG>" }) {
            System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\[\\?q\\])(.*?)(\\[\\?p\\]|<)", "$1AAA$3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[?q]AAA[?p]
[?q]AAA<RANDOM_TAG>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Very kind to add the explanation.
Just a quick question, how can I keep the '<'? Meaning, if I do a replace, $1 with AAA, then the output will be: AAARANDOM_TAG>. I would like to keep the < if possible so it would look: AAA<RANDOM_TAG>

Comment: Hmmm I'm not really sure I understood... please give me 2 minutes, I'd like to try something :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I'm using this tool to speed up testing: http://regexhero.net/tester/
Maybe it's also helpful to you since it does replacement in "real-time"

Comment: I just added some example about how you could use it in `Java`. Actually, I *modified the regex* to **capture** each part of the pattern: then, in your replacement `String`, `$1` refers to the `[?q]`, `$2` to the sequence you want to extract/replace and `$3` to the delimiter (either `[?p]` or `<`). Replacing the whole match with `$1AAA$3`, for example, only changes the *"central"* part. I hope that it's what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to match brackets in regex, you have to escape them, or they'll be interpreted as a character class. Also, you can add an "or" in regex by using a '|' in the middle of a group.

So your regex would look like this:

```
\\[\\?q\\](.*?)(<|\\[\\?p\\])
```

Edit: The reason I'm using double slashes to escape is because that's what the question used, so I assume he's using Java.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `\[\?q\](.*?)(?:\[\?q\]|<)`

From:

```
[?q]this is a test<RANDOM_TAG>
```

And:

```
[?q]this is a test[?q]RANDOM_TAG>
```

It matches: `this is a test`

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/zH1jC7).

Comment: After the `.*` you define a large character class, I think you wanted parens, not `[]`